# Looking for marriage (or birth) of Isabella Cubbin, born circa 1847 on Isle of Man?

Tags: 19th-century, marriage-records, isle-of-man

I am looking for the marriage (or birth) of Isabella Cubbin, born circa 1847 on the Isle of Man.

She married William Cowin at some point in the 1870s, but can't find a record of this.

She had children Fred, Catherine, Mary Ann, John James, Thomas, William,  Robert and Isabella Cowin on the Wirrall, Cheshire.

I found her maiden name Cubbin as two of her children, Fred and Isabella, emigrated to Canada and on their death records her maiden name is given.

She recorded on the 1911 census that she was born in Kirkpatrick on the Isle of Man.

I can't find any record of her marriage to William Cowin or a birth in Kirkpatrick.

Comment: Is it possible that she married more than once? If so, the informants on her children's death certificates may not have known her birth name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The marriage of William Cowin and Isabella Cubbin seems to have been registered in [Birkenhead Registration District](https://www.ukbmd.org.uk/reg/districts/birkenhead.html) in 1878:

[image: Cowin-Cubbin marriage]

The certificate should get you her father's name. You can then check on FamilySearch for the baptism record on the Isle of Man.

Comment: I've added a link to the page for Birkenhead Registration District on UKBMD which contains a timeline and a list of places within the district. The certificate should show whether the marriage was performed in the Registrar's Office or somewhere else.